# Хранение переменной после закрытия приложения

Tags: winapi

Есть определенная, общедоступная для множества приложений, переменная (массив булевых значений). Есть ли возможность как-то спроецировать и сохранить её в оперативной памяти, даже если все приложения, её использующие, закроются, чтобы в последующем для вновь открывшихся она была доступна, обойдясь без сохранения в файл/реестр?

( Имею ввиду потенциально (поскольку плохо разбираюсь в устройстве Windows) существующую некую глобальную область оперативной памяти )

Comment: Есть, это реестр виндОвса :) ещё можно написать на shared memory segment, но это будет не тривиальные задача.

Comment: @NewView, я же специально написал в вопросе про реестр, что не подходит. Да и в каком месте реестр - не файл? Самый натуральный файл, хоть и разделенный на несколько :)

А про Shared Memory Segment, если можно, поподробнее. Меня бы устроило, к примеру, хранить данные в процессе вроде Explorer.exe (выделяя кусок под данные через VirtualAllocEx например). Но где хранить, чтобы читать через ReadProcessMemory, указатель на эту память - ума не приложу.

Если имеете ввиду CreateFileMapping - уничтожается после закрытия процесса, который его создал :(

Comment: Да, именно [CreateFileMapping](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/Memory/creating-named-shared-memory), но мне кажется, что если не удалять хендл открытого файла основным процессом, то и файл до перезагрузки удален не будет, возможно я ошибаюсь? Есть ещё [такое](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/ntsecpkg/nc-ntsecpkg-lsa_create_shared_memory)

Comment: Вспомнил, вообще то [php умеет shmop](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php) под вин, можно заглянуть в исходники, как они там это решают.

Comment: @NewView, к сожалению, это всё шляпа :(